# Device detection morena 6

Tags: java, api, morena

As specified i have a problem with the detection of my cannon material DR-M160ii.
When I run the test provided the material is detected but when I include it in a project there is the error:
Failed to get list of twain sources SK.gnome.twain.TwainException: no TWAIN DATA Source installed
i'm running on windows 10 64bits
my project is a java project

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 32-bit java for running your application. TWAIN is working on 32-bit architecture.